# sorted() list not working as expected. Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, list, sorting

Trying to sort this list from lowest (399||1) to highest value (11064||2) while conserving the provided data format to be reused in an API loop request.

As you can see below, sorted() is not working as (I) expected. This is Python 2.7.
It looks like it sorts in pieces. Why would 1000-1100 come before 300-700, and then 8000? I cannot find this same issue posted anywhere.

```
sorted_d = sorted(d)
print sorted_d
```

Run:

```
[u'1053||1', u'1092||2', u'1093||1', u'1094||1', u'1094||2', u'1095||1', 
u'1095||2', u'1096||7', u'1096||8', u'1097||7', u'1097||8', u'11064||1', 
u'11064||2', u'399||1', u'412||1', u'412||2', u'413||1', u'414||1', 
u'434||2', u'616||1', u'617||1', u'618||1', u'619||1', u'620||1', u'621||1', 
u'622||1', u'727||1', u'8096||1', u'8097||1', u'8099||1', u'8101||1', 
u'8105||1', u'8112||1', u'8113||1', u'8140||1', u'8141||1', u'8142||1', 
u'8143||1', u'8144||1', u'8146||2', u'8150||1', u'8152||1', u'8153||1', 
u'8154||1', u'8157||1', u'8158||1', u'8159||1', u'8160||1', u'8161||1', 
u'8162||1', u'8163||1', u'8164||1', u'8165||1', u'8166||1', u'8167||1', 
u'8168||1', u'8169||1', u'8170||1', u'8171||1', u'8172||1', u'8173||1', 
u'8174||1', u'8175||1', u'8184||2', u'8184||3', u'8185||2', u'8185||3', 
u'8186||5', u'8186||6', u'8187||1', u'8188||2', u'8190||2', u'8191||1']
```

Assistance greatly appreciated.

Thx

Comment: Assistance in what? What is your question? What have you tried? What are you doing? What you're getting? What do you expect?

Comment: Hi kostek, I am trying to sort the list from lowest to the highest value. I thought that was clear. I apologize.

Comment: try something like `sorted_d = [int(n.split('||')[0]) for n in d]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also split the strings on the `||` and specify the first part as the [key parameter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
sorted_d = sorted(d, key = lambda x: int(x.split('||')[0]))

print sorted_d

[u'399||1', u'412||1', u'412||2', u'413||1', u'414||1', u'434||2', u'616||1', u'617||1', u'618||1', u'619||1', u'620||1', u'621||1', u'622||1', u'727||1', u'1053||1', u'1092||2', u'1093||1', u'1094||1', u'1094||2', u'1095||1', u'1095||2', u'1096||7', u'1096||8', u'1097||7', u'1097||8', u'8096||1', u'8097||1', u'8099||1', u'8101||1', u'8105||1', u'8112||1', u'8113||1', u'8140||1', u'8141||1', u'8142||1', u'8143||1', u'8144||1', u'8146||2', u'8150||1', u'8152||1', u'8153||1', u'8154||1', u'8157||1', u'8158||1', u'8159||1', u'8160||1', u'8161||1', u'8162||1', u'8163||1', u'8164||1', u'8165||1', u'8166||1', u'8167||1', u'8168||1', u'8169||1', u'8170||1', u'8171||1', u'8172||1', u'8173||1', u'8174||1', u'8175||1', u'8184||2', u'8184||3', u'8185||2', u'8185||3', u'8186||5', u'8186||6', u'8187||1', u'8188||2', u'8190||2', u'8191||1', u'11064||1', u'11064||2']
```

Comment: Hi downshift, I really need lowest (399||1) to highest value (11064||2).

Comment: Hi @S1NTAX , thanks for explaining that, I've fix it.

Comment: thank you so much!!! I apologize for initially not clearly stating my desired outcome. I have been using stackoverflow for around 3-4 years as a knowledge base, but this was the first time I had to post a question. I have learned from this experience and will be more precise next time.

Comment: very welcome, your question was great, I only misunderstood, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Because it's treating your '1053||1' data as strings and sorting as a string type instead of as a numeric value. So it effectively is sorting in this type of manner, ascending:

1
10
100
1000
2
20
200
2000

Comment: Thank you NickD! This explains what's happening, but I still can't figure out what to do.